# Test contagion effect between six FX series

Tags: model-selection, skewness, vector-autoregression, finance, unit-root

Here is how I test contagion effect between six FX series (deleted two due to VAR specification).

I first split the whole period into two subperiods exogenously suggested by Forbes Rigobon. By observation of the data, I decided to split the data by 2009 week 35.

Previous research before Forbes Rigobon (2002) based on correlation coefficients highlights the increase in interdependence or contagion in times of crisis. In contrast, Forbes and Rigobon correct the correlation coefficient for heteroscedasticity. The FR statistics here are corrected coefficient for heteroscedasticity.

The second table is a contagion test based on changes in coskewness based on Fry, Martin, Tang (2010). The coskewness test of contagion is based on identifying signiﬁcant changes in coskewness between a crisis period and a precrisis period. Two variants of the test are speciﬁed depending on whether the asset market at the source of the crisis is expressed in terms of returns or squared returns in computing coskewness.

I have computed the following results;

[image: FR_stats][image: coskewness]

Questions:

Why does FR test we accept all cases while when testing coskewness we reject all?

Comment: I doubt the FX rates could be I(2) rather than I(1). Perhaps there are neglected structural breaks that prevent the rejection of the second unit root? Regarding Q1, you have not told us what the FR test is and how it works. Regarding Q2, it is not clear how exactly you specify the VAR model. Yes, you have included a description of model building, but it is not entirely clear. What do you do, step by step? Regarding Q3, cannot understand the statement there. Finally, I doubt FX rates could be described by a VAR model as that would imply predictability of FX rates, which is counterintuitive.

Comment: I am afraid there is a bit too much going on in this post, so probably you should split it into a few concrete ones. E.g. one on model building for the FX rates, another on FR test and coskewness, etc.

Comment: @RichardHardy Sorry for the confusion. I have rewrite the question. Please inform me should there is any misunderstanding.

Comment: FR and FMT test for different things, don't they? If so, why should the test results be the same? Maybe you have one effect but not the other.